# Using python OpenCV to calculate vein leaf density

Tags: python, opencv

I'm a plant biologist who has been passed too much time doing repetitive tasks for image calculations using ImageJ. My specific problem is to find the length of the veins to afterward calculate the density (Note that the image have a scale).

[image]

I know python and I'm doing research on OpenCV and I think this library could do the job. But unfortunately, my knowledge of computer vision techniques and specifically OpenCV is poor. I came here to find advice on what method or methods should I use to achieve my goal!

Edit: The density is calculated as total vein length per leaf area. Reference image below
[image]

Comment: You're not going to like this answer, but you're going to need to find a grad student with some expertise in machine vision to help you.  This is a very large topic, and it's not something you're going to pick up with a series of short answers on a list like this.

Comment: "length of the veins" is unclear, as well as "density". show what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what exactly you do to compute the density or what you consider as veins. But here is one concept in Python/OpenCV.

Basically, one thresholds the image with the Otsu automatic threshold. Then optionally use morphology to remove small black regions that might not be part of the veins. Then invert the colors so the veins are white and count the number of black pixels in the image. The density would then be the count divided by the total number of pixels in the image.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("veins.jpg")
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# create a binary thresholded image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology to remove small black spots
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# invert so veins are white
veins = 255 - morph

# count non-zero pixels
count = np.count_nonzero(veins)

# compute density
density = count / (ht * wd)

# print density
print("density :", density)

# the density also should be just the graylevel average (mean) of the binary veins image divided by 255, so
density2 = np.mean(veins)/255

# print density2
print("density2:", density2)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("veins_binary.jpg", morph)

# show results
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thresholded and morphology cleaned image:

[image]

Density Result:

```
density : 0.41110921223958335
density2: 0.4111092122395833
```

Comment: Hi @fmw42. Thanks for your help! I did an edit adding a photo of what I'm searching for. The density is calculated as total vein length per leaf area. Is there any method to, based on your transformations, measure the length of the veins (the black section of the image you uploaded)?

Comment: I measured the length in pixels by the total number of black pixels. You could thin the black region using morphology to get a skeleton of the veins. Then measuring the count of black in the skeleton would give a better indication of length. See for example, https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html. You would need to invert the image so that the veins were white on black background to do the skeletonization.

Comment: Or in OpenCV, thinning at https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d2d/group__ximgproc.html#ga37002c6ca80c978edb6ead5d6b39740c

Comment: How was vein length computed in ImageJ?

Comment: it was completely manual, passing the mouse over each vein, measure the line and then totalizing :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that include skeletonization in Python/OpenCV/Skimage.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.morphology

img = cv2.imread("veins.jpg")
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# create a binary thresholded image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology to remove small black spots
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# invert so veins are white
veins = 1 - morph

# apply skeletonization
skeleton = skimage.morphology.skeletonize(veins)

# count non-zero pixels
count = np.count_nonzero(skeleton)

# compute density
density = count / (ht * wd)

# print density
print("density :", density)

# the density also should be just the graylevel average (mean) of the binary veins image divided by 255, so
density2 = np.mean(skeleton)

# print density2
print("density2:", density2)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("veins_skeleton.jpg", (255*skeleton).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))

# show results
cv2.imshow("thresh", (255*thresh).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imshow("morph", (255*morph).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imshow("skeleton", (255*skeleton).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Skeleton Image:

[image]

Density:

```
density : 0.032196451822916666
density2: 0.032196451822916666
```

Comment: thanks! your scripts are really useful. However, the value calculated manually for density in this image is about 13. Do you know any form to calculate the real length based on the reference in the image (200 μm)?

Comment: My density is count of white pixels per total image area. You just need to calibrate your image between pixel dimensions (width and height) and your micrometers.